# Jquery Mobile AJAX Links conflict

Tags: jquery, ajax, mobile

I'm relatively new to JQuery/JS so if you could please make your answers idiot proof it would be appreciated.

Can anyone suggest how I can edit Jquery Mobile so its AJAX link features are only applied to specific classes.

Problem is links that have their own separate AJAX functions are being overrun by JQuery Mobile.

I've tried `"ajaxEnabled: false"` on specific classes but this disables all AJAX features, where I need to disable just ajax links from JQuery Mobile.

I've search the problem and only found outdated info on using `.ajaxLinksEnabled : false;`  which no longer seems to be supported in Alpha 4, eg:

```
<code>
$(document).live("mobileinit", function() {
$.mobile.ajaxLinksEnabled :false;
$.mobile.ajaxFormsEnabled :false;
});
</code>
```

Any help would be great appreciated as spent hours trying to sort this now.

**UPDATE:**

I'm trying to use preventDefault:

```
`<script>
$('[data-role="page"]').bind('pageinit', function () {
    $('.addtocart_form').bind('click', function (e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        //add your custom ajax call here
         $('#addcartsubmit1').click(handleAddToCart);
    });
});
</script>`
```

This stops the JQ Mobile AJAX link BUT fails to call **functionhandleAddToCart**

HTML and PHP:

```
     `<form action="<?php echo $mm_action_url ?>index.php" method="post" name="addtocart" id="addtocart<?php echo $i ?>" class="addtocart_form" <?php if( $this->get_cfg( 'useAjaxCartActions', 1 ) && !$notify ) { echo 'onsubmit="handleAddToCart( this.id );return false;"'; } ?>>
  <div class="quantbox"> <?php echo $ps_product_attribute->show_quantity_box($product_id,$product_id); ?><br /></div>
  <div class="bsubmitcart"> <input type="submit" id="addcartsubmit1" style="border:none;" class="<?php echo $button_cls ?>" value="Add to Cart" title="<?php echo $button_lbl ?>" /> </div>`
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could add `data-ajax="false"` to your links, it's the jquery mobile way to disable Ajax on a link.

If you want a pure Class solution, maybe try to `.die()` on your link before binding your new ajax function.

http://jquerymobile.com/demos/1.0rc2/docs/pages/page-links.html

Comment: Hi, thanks for the response, I love stack, this sites a god send!.

I've been using data-ajax="false", problem is though it seems to remove ALL ajax functions. I'm trying to build it into a Virtuemart store and I need VM's native ajax to continue working so need to disable only mobile JQuery and leave other ajax functions running

Comment: Maybe use .die(click[handler]) to kill only the Jquery Mobile Ajax function ?

Comment: This seems like the best path. The live function I need to kill in JQMobile is: "$.mobile._registerInternalEvents = function(){" I can't get it to stop using  .die(click, _registerInternalEvents)

Comment: Ok this worked! My earlier problems was due to a ajax conflict but var $j = jQuery.noConflict(); fixed this also. Thanks v.much

Answer (score 0):

HTML:

```
<a href="#" class=".my-link-class">A Link</a>
```

JavaScript:

```
<script>
$('[data-role="page"]').bind('pageinit', function () {
    $(this).find('.my-link-class').bind('click', function (e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        //add your custom ajax call here
    });
});
</script>
```

If you are still having issues with jQuery Mobile running its own handler on the link, add `rel="external"` to the links.

Here is the documentation for linking in jQuery Mobile: http://jquerymobile.com/demos/1.0rc2/docs/pages/page-links.html

Comment: interesting, i'll give this ago and report back. Thanks!

Comment: Ok, preventDefault stops the ajax but i'm unable to call function handleAddToCart after this i'm using: 
 //add your custom ajax call here
   $('#IDname').click(handleAddToCart);